# Solutions of Laplace's equation for stream functions in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, flow, calculus, differential-equations

I was reading [Fluid Mechanics by Richard Fitzpatrick](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluidhtml/Fluidhtml.html). Somewhere in the book, he tried to solve [inviscid flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inviscid_flow) past a semi-infinite wedge https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluidhtml/node76.html .

The boundry condition for the problem is:

$$\psi (r,\alpha \ \pi/2) = \psi (r, 2 \pi - \alpha \ \pi/2) = \psi (r, \pi) = 0 \ ,$$

and the stream function satisfied the Laplace equation as follows:

$$\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \ \left( r \ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial \theta^2} = 0 \ .$$

The solution is directly given based on the boundary condition as:

$$\psi (r, \theta) = \alpha_0 + \beta_0 \ \mathrm{ln} + \sum_{m>0} \ (\alpha_m \ r^m + \beta_m \ r^{-m}) \ \mathrm{sin} \ [m \ (\theta - \theta_m)] \ .$$

Although the author thinks we can easily demonstrate the solution, it is not straightforward how it is done. I know that the general solution of the place equation we can think of is as follows,

However, I can not derive the given solution. I appreciate it if you could give me a hint.

Comment: Can you use [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) for the equations?

Comment: Are you familiar with solving PDEs via separation of variables?  The result given is just an application of that technique in cylindrical coordinates for these boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split the solution in some stages. You can find hand-written notes with the whole derivation here https://basics.altervista.org/stack-of-notes/.

### Separation of variables

It's possible to write the stream function as $\psi(r, \theta) = f(r) \, g(\theta)$, plug this expression into Poisson's equation for $\psi(r, \theta)$, and separate variables to get 2 ODEs

\begin{equation}
  0 = r \dfrac{d}{dr} \left( r \dfrac{d f(r)}{dr} \right) g(\theta) + \dfrac{f(r)}{r^2} \dfrac{d g(\theta)}{d\theta^2} \ 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\rightarrow \qquad  c = \dfrac{r}{f} \dfrac{d}{dr} \left( r \dfrac{d f(r)}{dr} \right) = - \dfrac{g''(\theta)}{g(\theta)} \ ,
\end{equation}
being $c$ a constant (that produces non-indentically zero solutions only for $c = \gamma^2 > 0$ - but I'll skip this proof. You can keep even non-positive values of $\gamma$ and find that these solutions are identically zero, or constant - irrelevant for the stream function - when you prescribe boundary conditions).

### Ordinary equations

The solutions of the ODEs are
\begin{equation}
  - \dfrac{g''(\theta)}{g(\theta)} = \gamma^2 \qquad \rightarrow \qquad g(\theta) = A \cos(\gamma \theta) + B \sin(\gamma \theta)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  \gamma^2 = \dfrac{r}{f} \dfrac{d}{dr} \left( r \dfrac{d f(r)}{dr} \right) \qquad \rightarrow \qquad f(r) = C r^{-\gamma} + D r^{\gamma} \ ,
\end{equation}
for every value of $\gamma > 0$. We should combine all the possible solutions for every values of $\gamma$ with an integral (since $\gamma$ can have continuous values), but here I'll do with a summation of discrete values, since this is the result we get when wee prescribe boundary conditions (and to avoid cumbersome notation, that you could be not used to).

### General solution

Thus, the general solution becomes
\begin{equation}
  \psi(r, \theta) = \sum_n \left( C_n r^{-\gamma_n} + D_n r^{\gamma_n} \right) \left( A_n \cos(\gamma_n \theta) + B_n \sin(\gamma_n \theta) \right) \ ,
\end{equation}
with the radial and azimutal components of the velocity
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  u_r & = \frac{1}{r} \partial_{\theta} \psi  = \sum_n \gamma_n \left( - C_n r^{-\gamma_n-1} + D_n r^{\gamma_n-1} \right) \left( - A_n \sin(\gamma_n \theta) + B_n \cos(\gamma_n \theta) \right) \\
  u_{\theta} & = - \partial_r \psi = - \sum_n \gamma_n \left( C_n r^{-\gamma_n-1} + D_n r^{\gamma_n-1} \right) \left( A_n \cos(\gamma_n \theta) + B_n \sin(\gamma_n \theta) \right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

### Prescribe boundary conditions

Prescribing the boundary conditions $u_{\theta}(r,\pi) = u_{\theta, \beta} = 0$, with $\beta = \alpha \pi / 2$, we get
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
 u_r(r, \theta) & = \sum_n \gamma_n \left( - C_n r^{-\gamma_n-1} + D_n r^{\gamma_n-1}  \right) \cos(\gamma_n(\pi-\theta)) \\
 u_\theta(r,\theta) & = \sum_n \gamma_n \left(  C_n r^{-\gamma_n-1} + D_n r^{\gamma_n-1}  \right) \sin(\gamma_n(\pi-\theta)) \ ,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
where $\gamma_n = \frac{n \pi}{\pi - \beta}$

You can find the details at this external link https://basics.altervista.org/stack-of-notes/. In particular, the harmonic functions combine like that in order to have non-trivial zero solutions (as a result of the solution of a determined homogeneous linear system - You can find details in the "green section" in the notes).

If one prescribes finite velocity for finite distance from the wedge, the coefficients $C_n$ must be zero, so that the solution reads
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
 u_r(r, \theta) & = - \sum_n d_n r^{\gamma_n-1} \cos(\gamma_n(\pi-\theta)) \\
 u_\theta(r,\theta) & = - \sum_n d_n r^{\gamma_n-1} \sin(\gamma_n(\pi-\theta)) \ ,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  \psi(r,\theta) = \sum_n  \dfrac{d_n}{\gamma_n} r^{\gamma_n} \sin(\gamma_n(\pi-\theta)) \ .
\end{equation}

This expression is the superposition of infinite solutions that satisfy all the condition prescribed so far, but many of them are not-physical, as depicted in the picture below.

[image]

The physical solution is the term corresponding to $\gamma_1 \frac{ \pi}{\pi - \beta}$, and thus we set = 0 all the coefficients $d_n$ except for $d_1$.

### Select the "physical" solution among the infinite number of possible solutions

The selected physical solution thus reads
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
u_r(r, \theta) & = - d_1 r^{\gamma_1-1} \cos(\gamma_1(\pi-\theta)) \\
 u_\theta(r,\theta) & = - d_1 r^{\gamma_1-1} \sin(\gamma_1(\pi-\theta)) \ ,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  \psi(r,\theta) = \dfrac{d_1}{\gamma_1} r^{\gamma_1} \sin(\gamma_1(\pi-\theta)) \ .
\end{equation}

Comment: I deeply appreciate your help. I learned a lot from your notes. However, some questions popped into my mind we I went through your notes. It would be awesome if I could ask more in-depth questions.

Comment: You're welcome. You could ask here on SE, or maybe it's better here https://basics.altervista.org/irrotational-flow-around-a-wedge/. It's not the cleanest way to do it, but let's move there, without any limits to the number of characters

Comment: are you still alive?